# wp_mail() method already exists from a different plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, phpmailer, wp-mail

I am using the Mailster plugin to send newsletters and also for system emails on my WooCommerce website.

After a recent update, I am getting this error message

```
The wp_mail() method already exists from a different plugin! Please disable it before using Mailster for system mails!
More info: - /wp-includes/pluggable.php:174
```

But I don't know of any plugin that uses for email purposes.

Most importantly, isn't `pluggable.php` is one of the core files of WordPress?

Any pointers to resolve this issue is much appriciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Make a database backup… Disable all plugins except WooCommerce. Enable plugins one by one, to find out which plugin is responsible (checking each time if this error is thrown). When you found the responsible plugin, contact their support and report the bug.

Comment: If you have command line access you can search for it much faster with `grep -R “function wp_mail” /path/to/wordpress`